# Passing an id reference to onClick function on xml file

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

Here's the xml code:

```html
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corner">

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name_resource"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/name"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit_create_resource_button"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/create"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:onClick="@{() -> customDialogViewModel.onSetSharedResourceName()}"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and here's the called function:

```html
fun onSetSharedResourceName(name: String) {
        ....some code....
    }
```

I want to give the EditText content as onSetSharedResourceName() function.
How can I make a reference to name_resource?

Thank :)

Comment: It really depends where that string param in `onSetSharedResourceName` come from.

Answer (score 0):

first you should declare the view inside class with lateinit and add the dataType

```
private lateinit var nameResource: EditText
private lateinit var submitCreateResourceButton: Button
```

and then initialize inside onCreate with findViewById function and call the id

```
nameResource = findViewById(R.id.name_resource)
submitCreateResourceButton = findViewById(R.id.submit_create_resource_button)
```

then you can use it as view inside onCreate, for example:

```
nameResource.setOnClickListener {//write your code here}
```